# C# & Lua MD5 Hashing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lua, md5

I am having some issues trying to match an MD5 encryption with salt from Lua to C#. Meaning, I have it hashing and salting the account password in Lua, but I need to match that exact same encryption in C# as I am developing a website in C# that needs to use the same database and accounts as the Lua script.

I've tried for quite some time now trying to match them, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it right.

Lua hash:

```
if (string.len(cpypassword) ~= 64) then
            password = md5(Newsalt .. password)
            local result = mysql:query("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username='" .. username .. "'")
            if (mysql:num_rows(result)>0) then
                local insertid = mysql:query_insert_free("UPDATE accounts SET password='" .. mysql:escape_string(password) .. "' WHERE username='".. mysql:escape_string(username) .."'")
                triggerClientEvent(client, "accounts:login:attempt", client, 1, "Password changed!\nThank you." ) 
            end
        end
```

I've tried a variety of different ways to do MD5 hash in C#, but none of them matches, so here I am now, asking you for suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Lua function generates this as an example:
CFA62AA942A84781B1C101D6D583B641

Same example generated in C# with the C# hashing:
DSqwG/W1LNbHsCEkHNAUpg==

C# code (just one of the things I tried, I found much simpler ones, but this is the latest one I tried, just copied out of a tutorial)

```
public class Encryption
    {
        public static string EncryptorDecrypt(string securityCode, string key, bool encrypt)
        {

            byte[] toEncryptorDecryptArray;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform;

            // Transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasing = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] keyArrays = md5Hasing.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(securityCode));

            md5Hasing.Clear();

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keyArrays, Mode = CipherMode.ECB, Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7 };

            if (encrypt == true)
            {
                toEncryptorDecryptArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

                cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

            }

            else
            {

                toEncryptorDecryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(key.Replace(' ', '+'));

                cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();

            }

            byte[] resultsArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptorDecryptArray, 0, toEncryptorDecryptArray.Length);

            tdes.Clear();

            if (encrypt)
            { //if encrypt we need to return encrypted string

                return Convert.ToBase64String(resultsArray, 0, resultsArray.Length);

            }

            //else we need to return decrypted string

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultsArray);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your Lua function producing? What does your C# code look like?

Comment: @wgraham - Sorry about that, the question has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided for C# is not generating an MD5 hash; instead it is hashing the `securityCode` and using it as a key for TripleDES.

Take a look [at this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx) (copied relevant bits out):

```
public string CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast assistance! This fixed my issue, and the outcome is now the exact same, thank you VERY much!